# Expression trees in .NET - Libraries?

Tags: c#, .net, expression-trees

I have recently written a dynamic querying tool using expression trees and as I went the power of expression trees began to dawn on me. My querying tool could also form the basis of a reporting tool, a dynamic decision engine and maybe other cases where you need to work with dynamic objects in abstract ways.

The process has been painful (recursive calls to generic methods by reflection - ugh) so I am wondering whether anyone has created a generic library that might harness the power of expression trees to accomplish some of these kinds of tasks? I have seen [PredicateBuilder](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx) but does anyone know of any others?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Generic operators](http://www.pobox.com/~skeet/csharp/miscutil/usage/genericoperators.html) (in [MiscUtil](http://www.pobox.com/~skeet/csharp/miscutil/)) is a pretty well utilised bit of code based on expression trees; very simple, but very versatile. Some other ideas:

- [cloning objects](http://groups.google.com/group/microsoft.public.dotnet.languages.csharp/browse_thread/thread/d9722a51b04300a/0edae91abc1c0f1a#0edae91abc1c0f1a)
- [dynamic ordering](http://groups.google.com/group/microsoft.public.dotnet.languages.csharp/browse_thread/thread/9ca28e3f0205bb87/c5b6c43ef3f38ae9)
- [dynamic LINQ](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx)

(lots of others)

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at the DLR?  I don't know much about it in detail, but my understanding is that the expression-tree mechanism which is behind the scenes in Linq-to-SQL has effectively been published in the DLR.

Comment: No, this is not true. It looks similar, but the DLR is by far inferior.

Comment: DLR trees share a lot of common ground with Expression, and IIRC they are a bit more merged in .NET 4.0 CTP.

Answer (score 1):

[NJection](http://www.njection.net/) is a library that deals with code injection through configuration files.

[NJection.LambdaConverter](https://github.com/sagifogel/NJection.LambdaConverter) is a library that transforms delegates to expression trees.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at LINQ and the IQueryable interface? That's how they implemented LINQ to SQL, etc.